# Capturing filled html table

Tags: php, html, email, html-table

Do you have any suggestion for this particular problem.

I have fairly complex html table that is filled by user. I have some JavaScript function who is generating new row when is needed. I want to email this filled table when user hit button. So my question is how do I "capture" filled table, and then email it? 
Of course I will be using php mail function.

I was thinking to print-screen where table is, and attach it to email. But there must be a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the `$_POST` to send the email? When the user submits the table, you post your information, format it and email the posted information to the user. You said your table was filled in by the user. So, I assume you're using input fields.

When the JavaScript writes a new row, it can create a new array element in PHP by using the HTML element's name.

The would look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="textname[]" value="Value1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!-- Created with JavaScript -->
      <input type="text" name="textname[]" value="Value2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="submit" /></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

The array would be like this when posted:

```
array(
  ['textname'] =>
    array(
     [0] => 'Value1',
     [1] => 'Value2'
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

send the table via AJAX (use the getElementById-function to get the table-content) to a PHP-Script and use the mail-function

```
<div id='content'>
<table>
<!-- your table -->
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function send()
{
var table = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
// send the content of table via ajax (use jquery or build your own webrequest-object)
}
</script>

<button onclick="send()" value="Send" />
```

Comment: Can you explain me please how to send table via AJAX? The PHP part is not problem, when i get variable to email.

Comment: Hi, guys! Here, Stanislav http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp you have the basic lessons you'll need for your purpose.

Comment: Thank you for help, but I think that i will be using $_POST. @Biotox -s proposition...